# Azure Devops Pipeline won't trigger after a Pull Request merge

Tags: azure-devops

This is most peculiar.

I got this repository and pipeline. The pipelines are based on Yaml.

Here are the triggering definition:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - "*"
  paths:
    include:
      - api/
      - devops/build/azure-pipeline-backend.yml
      - devops/build/stages/build-backend-stage.yml
      - devops/build/stages/deploy-backend-stage.yml
```

This repository has a branch policy to get changes verified before allowing them to be completed. The above pipeline triggers for all branches including Pull Request checks. It won't trigger for the default branch though after a pull request completion.

The triggers have not been overridden and they should follow the ones defined above.
[image]

I've setup another repository and tried a similar setup and the triggering works fine so I am beginning to think that there may be some policy or something elsewhere that I am not aware of.

Comment: Try removing the "branches" or change the include from `- "*"` to `- *`

Comment: Tried that, it's not it

Comment: @Konstantinos 
Did you ever find a solution? I'm seeing the same issue.

Comment: @ChrisWeber I think it's a bug with DevOps. Creating brand new pipelines seems to have solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though your path filters are not matching the changes.

Add a wildcard to the `api/*` path

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - "*"
  paths:
    include:
      - api/*
      - devops/build/azure-pipeline-backend.yml
      - devops/build/stages/build-backend-stage.yml
      - devops/build/stages/deploy-backend-stage.yml
```

Comment: as I said, the trigger works for all branches except when a PR has completed(which should trigger the default branch that they usually get merged in).

Wildcards are not supported in paths(it's the same as writing "/" vs "/*".

Also the wildcard character in the branches needs quotes according to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers

Comment: We use wildcards in our paths in our project which has over 70 pipelines, they are supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#wildcards

Comment: You are correct about the branch wildcard being wrapped in quotes. I'll update my answer

Comment: Here's a test repo where everything works as expected:
https://gist.github.com/kotsaris/b521953fe2d6923d103f9fa54b4656fd

Comment: I wonder if because you're specifying all branches and batch that the build-validation is incorrectly identifying that it has already built.  We typically specify only key branches for continuous-integration triggers (master, develop, release/*) as we don't want CI on every single push to feature branches. We rely on the branch policy on the PR to accomplish this. ie -- only build on a feature branch when it's ready for approval

Comment: Sounds like an interesting theory. Might give it a try. That said, check the link of a setup that works which also uses * and batch: true